# Cancelling an input after a specified time limit with Python-Asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Hello there i am trying to use Async to take an input if given and continue if its not given cancel the task and use the default input.

```
state = 'routine'

async def start():
    while True: 
        state = input('Enter state')
        print(state)

async def main():
    task = asyncio.Task(start())
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    task.cancel()
    print(state)
    with suppress(asyncio.CancelledError):
        await task
```

There is an infinite loop, user is given 5 seconds to provide an input and if user has not given any input use the default one (state).It's stuck on taking input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input` is a blocking function, so it must not be called from a coroutine. A hint that your `start` coroutine is not correctly written is that it doesn't `await` anything. Take a look at [aioconsole](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole) for an async equivalent of `input` and others.

Also, create tasks using [`asyncio.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task) (or [`loop.create_task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task) prior to Python 3.7), not by calling the `Task` constructor directly.